# Standalone user management library that supports Doctrine ORM?

Tags: php, authentication, doctrine, authorization, user-management

I can't find a standalone system that I can use for user management (authentication,authorization, register, password reminders...).

The **closest it gets** is using Symfony and **[FOSUserBundle](http://symfony2bundles.org/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle)** but because it's a Symfony Bundle it seem to be dependant on the framework. Is there a way to separate these or at least to load only few components of symfony?

I've used symfony before and I like it; I just don't need the entire framework for the current project.

I couldn't find other solutions.

Comment: What framework do you use in your current project?

Comment: There's no current project :) . I'm currently making a design decision before I start. I want modules as user management and routing to be as much decoupled as possible so I won't be relying on an entire framework if I can't disassemble it bit by bit and combine them into a Frankenstein.

I want to use this system in old projects too.

Comment: Did you manage using it in your solution, @antitoxic? I'm looking for a way to check the authentification of user logged in via symfony in an external script. Can you help?

Answer (score 3):

Honnestly, most projects have custom needs. Even using something like FOSUserBundle you'll have to re-implement or edit a big part of it.

If your project is not a "time-attack" project, take ~a week to build your own librairy. I'm not saying you should reinvent the wheel --base yourself on existing code--, but I think that most of the time, people that really take the time to design before starting a projects are in projects that are big enought to justify this kind of custom implementation.

Comment: "base yourself on existing code" What existing code? :) That's why I'm doing the entire thing - I want to know what I can base the user system on. I'll extend it of course. However I should be able to keep the original files untouched so that I receive updates to the vendor system.

Comment: FOSUserBundle was a good suggestion... no ? And I'm talking about doing your own librairy, not extending one. ;)

Comment: I can use it as an example yes :) I'm asking though whether I can actually use something, not to do a rewrite. Isn't this the main point of OO and modularity - to be reusable. Symfony Bundles doesn't even fit Silex (which is a `symfony lite microframwork`.

Answer (score 1):

You could give a try to https://github.com/symfony/Security its Symfony2 component but can be used "standalone".

Depenedencies from composer.json file (https://github.com/symfony/Security/blob/master/composer.json#L19-24)

```
"symfony/event-dispatcher": ">=2.1",
"symfony/http-foundation": ">=2.1",
"symfony/http-kernel": ">=2.1"
```

Comment: Do you have an implementation of this working? Because as far as I see it also need HttpFoundation and Routing. May be even more?

Comment: HttpFoundation and Routing are both pieces of Symfony that can be separated from the core and used at your own discretion. I see no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I don't need these, Dan. I mentioned I want to use the code in old projects. I don't want to drag other components in.

Comment: It's not standalone it require dependencies indicated in  https://github.com/symfony/Security/blob/master/composer.json#L19-24, no I don't have any implementation.

Comment: I didn't know that composer.json have these. Thanks!